# Extend a java class with <T extends SomeClass> generic type in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generic-type-argument

I have a class in java that accepts a generic type that extends another class
How can I extend the first class in Kotlin?

I've already tried using out keyword but it's no good.

**EntityFragment.java**

```
public abstract class EntityFragment<T extends EntityModule> extends BaseFragment {

public EntityFragment(T module, boolean root) {
        //some code
}
```

My kotlin class that I'm trying to write is as below:

```
open class WidthChangeNotifierFragment<out T : EntityStorage>(t: T, root: Boolean) : EntityFragment<T>(t, root) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `out` keyword in this case. You can just write

```
open class WidthChangeNotifierFragment<T : EntityModule>(t: T, root: Boolean) : EntityFragment<T>(t, root)
```

Comment: That's right. I had used EntityStorage instead of EntityModule and got the "type argument is not within its bound" error when I didn't use the "out" keyword.